# Merge by not unique key for large datasets in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset `all`:

```
UserKey  kind_id   user_name  sex
1   7472505       2       Jane    <NA>
2   4564687       5     Natalie    F
3   4564687       2     Natalie    F
4   4564687       2     Natalie    F
5   4564687       5     Natalie    F    
6   5257695       2       Nelly    F


> dim(all_orders)
[1] 104979393         4
```

and I have to add new column `dsex` from another dataset `names` (dictionary of names):

```
name dsex
1 Albine    F
2 Nataly    F  
3 Nelly     F
4 Jane      F
5 Miko      F

> dim(names)
[1] 82187     2
```

matching the `user_name` from first dataset and `name` from dictionary.

My attempts:

**1. sapply and fucnction**

```
get_sex <- function(input){
sex <- names[names$name==input,]$dsex
return(as.character(sex))
}

all$dsex <- sapply(all$user_name, get_sex)
```

It works, but not for large dataset.

**2. dplyr and data.table**

```
names <- as.data.table(names, key = 'name')

a <- all %>% group_by(UserKey) %>% summarise(dsex = get_sex(user_name))
```

Do not works for large dataset.

**3. merge**

```
allm <- merge(all, names, by.x = c('user_name'), by.y = c('name'), all.x = T, all.y = F)
```

Much better, but not for my dataset (5 mln rows were ok).

So what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: If you convert them to `data.table`, try `all[names, on = c("user_name" = "name"), dsex := dsex]`

Comment: For #2, you're using a summarise in the dplyr version - is there a particular reason you're grouping by and then summarizing instead of doing a join? I'd think from looking at your data that left_join() would do the trick. Generally merge < *apply < dplyr < data.table, with the different being massive between merge and dplyr.